# How to paramaterize a tractrix?

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

\begin{cases}
 & \text{ } x(t)=t - a \frac{\sinh (\frac{t}{a})}{\cosh (\frac{t}{a})}  \\ 
 & \text{ } y(t)= \frac{a}{\cosh (\frac{t}{a})}
\end{cases}

According to the exercise, I need to see the parametric view of traxis, i.e. bring to normal view of traxis using some substitution, but no idea which one

Comment: That is already a parametrization, a map $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$. By any chance is it what you need to obtain an implicit equation, an equation of the form $f(x,y)=0$?

Comment: See [this site](https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/tractrice/tractrice.shtml). Besides tractis $\rightarrow$ tractrix

Comment: I just asked the wrong question, edited already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already parameterized the tractrix. in $ [(x(t),y(t) )]= (z(\theta),r(\theta))$ form in 3D suitable for a surface of revolution where geometrically angle $\theta $ is reckoned from cuspidal equator in polar coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$.

$$ z(\theta)/a= \theta-\tanh \theta \,;r(\theta)/a= sech \,\theta \tag1 $$

If slope $\phi$ to z-axis is a parameter. Tangent length is constant $=a$.

$$ z(\theta) = a( \log\, \tan \frac{\phi}{2}-\cos \phi ) \,;r(\theta)=a \sin \phi. \tag2 $$

Eliminating $\phi$

$$ z = a\, sech^{-1}(r/a) -\sqrt{a^2-r^2} \tag3 $$

Equn 1) can be rewritten by means of arc length $s= a \theta$ reckoned from cuspidal equator:

$$ z(s)= s-\tanh(s/a)\,;r(s) = sech \,(s/a) \tag4 $$

Comment: I just asked the wrong question, edited already